# How to edit footnote in LyX

Tags: beamer, lyx

Is it be possible to edit the footnote of the title of the presentation? I want to edit the author name (because by default it comes with department name) and title of the presentation (because it is quite large). Can it be different from the main title?

Comment: Please always add to your questions a minimal version of your code showing the relevant settings.

Comment: I am not using any coding. Just using LYX.

Comment: Ah... I didn't know that LyX doesn't produce code.

Comment: Your thoughts betray you @biostat. I feel the good in you, the conflict. Come over to the LaTeX side of the force.

Comment: Also, LyX does produce code. Maybe it's in a container, but the code is there. Otherwise it wouldn't be LaTeX. Anyway, I used to collaborate with a guy who used LyX. It produces horrible code.

Comment: I know in back of LYX there is Latex. I can export code, but I am unable to compile on other machine. This is my experience with LYX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suppress the parentheses, you can (re)define the `footline` beamer template (as defined in the outer theme `infolines` which is internally used by `Madrid`); for your other question, you can use the optional argument of `\title`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Add to preamble from here ------------------
\usetheme[secheader]{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor%~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
% To here ----------------------

\author{A.U. Thor}
\title[The Title in footline]{The Title in the document}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}  

\begin{frame}\maketitle\end{frame}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{adafdg}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: This is the whole code for a LaTeX user, so just include the marked part in your LyX preamble

Comment: should I put this text in LYX peamable?

Comment: @biostat: I guess so; I've never used LyX.

Comment: include everything from `\usetheme...` to `\makeatother` in your preamble. The rest is created by you in your main document.